# Understanding a particular transformation of an integral given in a proof

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Using the theorem of mean values find the sign of the integral...
>   $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi}{\sin x \over x}dx= \int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin x \over x}dx+\int_{\pi}^{2 \pi}{\sin x \over x}dx$$
>   Then: $[x-\pi=t ; dx=dt]$
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin x \over x}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin(t+ \pi) \over t+ \pi}dt \, \,\color{red}{\fbox{=}} \int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin x \over x}dx-\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin(x)\over x+ \pi }dx$$

How does one see the (boxed, red) equality?

Comment: this is $\sin(\pi + t) = -\sin (t)$

Comment: First: $\sin (t+ \pi) = -\sin t$ (I hope this is well known). Second: the variable in a definite integral is a mute variable. This means that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(t) dt = \int_a^b f(\%) d\% = \int_a^b f(\rho) d\rho = \dots$ and so on. Third: you can put minus sign out of the integral.

Comment: Why these asterisks $**$ ? Typo's ?

Comment: Very well, this question is soon to be deleted much appreciation for the help !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I believe Bozo's intent was to highlight the step whose justification was unclear; I modified his LaTeX just a bit to clarify this some (I hope).

Comment: @Travis. Thanks for clarifying for me. Since I am almost blind, typos like that make me misunderstanding things. Cheers :-)

Comment: I get now how $\int_{0}^{\pi}{sin(t+ \pi) \over t+ \pi}dx=- \int_{0}^{\pi}{sin(t) \over t+ \pi}dt $ how do i conclude the rest if$  x\neq t$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici (At least with lenses) I am not almost blind, but it still took me a bit of staring to sort out what was going on myself.

Comment: @BozoVulicevic What is "the rest" here? The inequality you mention is the justification for the equality. Do you mean, what is the justification for getting from the r.h.s. of the first display equation to the l.h.s. of the second? (In which case, the fault is mostly mine for the misleading edit.)

Comment: @Crostul How do we know that $t$ is a mute variable ?

Comment: @Crostul Is there a theorem that justifies that? I'm very interested in which ?

Comment: This is a definite integral, which results in a number, so the name of variable doesn't matter. Replacing $t$ with $x$ doesn't change anything

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

if you have $f(x)=F'(x)$, you can change the ''symbol'' for the variable, i.e write $t=x$, and you have: $f(t)=F'(t)$.

Than:

$$
\int_a^b f(x)=F(x)|_a^b=F(b)-F(a)
$$

$$
\int_a^b f(t)=F(t)|_a^b=F(b)-F(a)
$$

In your case you have:
$$
\int_0^\pi\dfrac{\sin (t+\pi)}{t+\pi}dt=-\int_0^\pi\dfrac{\sin t}{t+\pi}dt=-\int_0^\pi\dfrac{\sin x}{x+\pi}dt
$$

Comment: How is this possible : take t=x+2; f(x)=x ; $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx =\int_{0}^{1}x dx \neq \int_{0}^{1}(x+2)dx !!!! $$

Comment: I still haven't gotten a complete answer for this question..

Comment: You simply change the name of the variable, this menas that the substitution is $t=x$.

Comment: Do you not understand or something, $$x \neq  t !!!! x= t+ \pi$$

Comment: I've adde another step. I hope it can help  :)